# Count non adjacent blank cells in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Screenshot

[image]

I'm trying to count the number of cells that are blank in a selection of cells in a row. The formula I'm using follows this format:

```
=COUNTBLANK(BE4)+COUNTBLANK(BG4)+COUNTBLANK(BH4)+COUNTBLANK(BI4)
```

It works okay for some rows but for others the total count isn;t correct e.g. screenshot of row 6 which is returning a total of 1 when it should be 3.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: 1. You could technically add four ISBLANK instead of COUNTBLANK, less typing.  But 2. COUNTBLANK() see a cell that has a formula that returns `""` as not blank.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},BE4,BG4,BH4,BI4)=""))
```

This will pick up truly blank and cells that have formula that return an empty string `""`